# Am I misunderstanding variable access in C#?

Tags: c#, mono

I have a `Utils.dll` with source that looks something like this:

```
using System;

namespace Utils
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static string B()
        {
            string foo = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...";
            return "abc";
        }
    }
}
```

and an executable with source that looks something like this:

```
using System;
using Utils;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A.B());
        Console.WriteLine(A.B.foo);
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to access `foo` from any C# executable compiled with `Utils.dll`, but apparently not; the compiler (I'm using Mono) says `error CS0119: Expression denotes a 'method group', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'type' was expected`. I've tried prepending `public`, `static` and `const` in various permutations to `string foo`, with no success.

Am I misunderstanding how variable access in C# works? Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: foo is a local variable, scoped on method B().    You cant access it from Main because its out of scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you're misunderstanting.

Your foo string is declared as a local variable, so only the method B can access to it.  By the way, i also don't really know if your B object is a method (in that case it should have been B() and not B)  or a property (but B hasn't got get or set so..).

Why do you need to access to foo from B, if B returns "abc" and not foo ?

Comment: `B` is now a method. This is in effect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/292636), but I'm curious as to whether this is at all possible (the 'problem' is now an unproblem).

Comment: @JoshHolland: No, it's not possible to access a local variable. You must utilize other faculties (e.g., `return`, `ref`, `out`) to pass back that variable to the caller. Maybe you're misunderstanding/mixing the concepts of [class members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx) and [local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yup, appears I am. Thanks for the links!